Cоздание progress bar на JS с отображением прогресса на странице
Делаю практику на курсе по js и по заданию нужно сделать функцию прогресс с параметром тайм, которая за заданное время изменяет размер  дива, использую scaleX, с отображением процента на странице.
Сделала пока так, но когда добавила процент див стал заполняться в разы быстрее и выходит за пределы страницы. Подскажите, что не так.


/* Добавлено для визуализации в сниппете */
const div = document.querySelector('.progress-bar');
const timeEl = document.getElementById('time');
/* ===================================== */
  
function progress(time) {
  let startPoint = 0;
  div.style.transform = 'scaleX(0)';
  let speed = time / 31;
  let timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (startPoint > 31) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
      div.style.transform = `scaleX(${startPoint})`;
      timeEl.textContent = `${(startPoint / 31) * 100} %`;
    }

    startPoint++;
  }, speed);
}

/* запуск */ 
progress(time); 
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(227, 227, 207);
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.progress-bar {
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 195);
  transition: transform ease-in-out .5s;
  transform-origin: left;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress-bar"></div>
  <span id="time"></span>
</div>




Добавьте в вопрос html/css разметку div, что бы можно было воспроизвести ошибку

Добавила. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему добавление текстконтент влияет на отрисовку дива

что за число, как тебе кажется, передается в качестве параметра в scaleX?

Если я правильно посмотрел, то div изначально в ширину 41px. Когда вы его scaleX растягиваете в 31 раз, то его ширина станет... Думаю, калькулятор у вас есть :)

Чем вас не устраивает ?

ScaleX на глаз подбирала, просто до того, как добавила строчку с текстконтент, див был нормального размера. Поэтому возник вопрос, почему при ее добавлении див растягивается сильнее, чем без нее)

scaleX, чтобы объект принял установленные размеры, должен быть не более 1. Код должен быть такой: div.style.transform = scaleX(${startPoint / 31}); Но я бы посмотрел в сторону идеи, которая используется в построении progress. Там используется такое свойство, как inlineSize


/* Добавлено для визуализации в сниппете */
const div = document.querySelector('.progress-bar');
const bar = document.querySelector('.bar');
const timeEl = document.getElementById('time');
/* ===================================== */
  
function progress(time) {
  let startPoint = 0;
  bar.style.inlineSize = '0%';
  let speed = time / 31;
  let timer = setInterval(() => {
    if (startPoint > 31) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
      //div.style.transform = `scaleX(${startPoint / 31})`;
      bar.style.inlineSize = `${(startPoint / 31) * 100}%`;
      timeEl.textContent = `${parseInt((startPoint / 31) * 100)}%`;
    }

    startPoint++;
  }, speed);
}

/* запуск */ 
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  progress(10000); 
});
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgb(227, 227, 207);
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.progress-bar {
  min-width: 500px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}

.bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(128, 128, 195);
  inline-size: 0%;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress-bar"><div class="bar"></div></div>
  <span id="time">0%</span>
  <button>ПУСК</button>
</div>




Спасибо за ответ!

@Саша, и здесь есть тоже ошибка. Вы не аннулируете объект интервала при нажатии на кнопку.
Пример дан только в пределах понятия общей проблемы.
